# Modify ASP.NET PasswordRecovery Control?

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to modify the ASP.NET PasswordRecovery Control.

I was able to use the "UserNameTemplate" to modify the layout. However, it seems like the control still wraps everything in an HTML table element, which is producing undesired results.

Is there a way to turn the table wrap off?

The problem is being caused because I want to add a cancel button to the page as well.

If I try to add it to the UserNameTemplate directly it obviously complains that is DOESNT know about this button.

If I add it AFTER the PasswordRecovery control it DOESNT display with the other controls.

I tried using a jQuery hack to remove the table elements, but that seems to remove all child elements as well, and ALL that displays is the "Cancel" button I added.

```
        <asp:PasswordRecovery ID="resetuserpassword" runat="server" 
        MailDefinition-BodyFileName="~/ResetPasswordEmailTemplate.html" 
        OnSendingMail="resetuserpassword_SendingMail"
        Width="300px" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Small" UserNameTitleText="" >
        <InstructionTextStyle Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Small" />
        <MailDefinition BodyFileName="~/ResetPasswordEmailTemplate.html"></MailDefinition>
        <UserNameTemplate>
            <div>Please Enter your Username</div>
            <div><asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName" style="display:none;"></asp:Label></div>
            <div><asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></div>
            <div><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="PasswordRecovery1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator></div>
            <div><asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal></div>
            <div><asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" CommandName="Submit" Text="Submit" ValidationGroup="PasswordRecovery1" style="display: inline-block;" /></div> 
            </UserNameTemplate>
        </asp:PasswordRecovery>
        <div><asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="btnCancel_OnClick" style="display: inline-block;" > </asp:Button></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $( "table" ).remove();
    $( "tr" ).remove();
    $( "td" ).remove();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around that will be suitable... I was able to place the submit button outside of the PasswordRecovery control, which allowed me to style it uniformly with the cancel button, which was also outside of the control. I imagine to get it inside of the usernametemplate I would have to override to Password control, and add the button as a child.